# Оценка производительности regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, производительность

Какой алгоритм используется в regex c#?
Мой метод состоит в основном из операций с регулярными выражениями, интересует как оценить асимптотическую производительность метода?

Comment: В .NET [используется](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e347654k(v=vs.110).aspx) NFA-реализация - мощная, но медленная по сравнению с DFA. А главное - всё зависит от текста, по которому осуществляется поиск и от самой регулярки. Можно написать такое регулярное выражение, которое приведёт к бесконечному циклу.

Comment: ну да, я про это читал,правда на примере java. Ну а есть какой -то способ примерной оценки? Логарифмическая, линейная и т.п.? на примере циклов-то все понятно, а тут...